# How to integrate php application with SAP using web service?

Tags: php, integration, sap-erp

I need some basic idea for how to integrate SAP Application with my PHP Application. And the client needs to get the employees list from SAP and after calculation send the resultant data against each employee in particular date...

But I have no idea about SAP:

- What will be the initial requirements and what should I require from the client (SAP user)?
- How will I communicate with SAP using PHP?

Comment: to be of any help we'd first need to know what SAP application you're talking about. There is a few of them and some are based on completely different frameworks and technologies.

Comment: i just need to know how can we get data from SAP via Web Service , either user will give me a link to add ,update or there is some dependent application which i can get data

Comment: "SAP" is a software company, not a product. Are you talking about SAP ERP or CRM (which are netweaver based), maybe B1 (which is a product based on .Net technology) or even BusinessObjects, which is something different entirely.

Comment: Thank you for information , i am stuck here , my client will give me SAP employee data and i will integrate it in my APP (PHP and MSSQL ) , i just want to know that which technology i used to communicate with SAP ERP environment and share my own APP data with SAP , it may be ERP or CRM.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek.. can you please tell me what should i require from the client and the flow of this process. appreciate you answer

Comment: well, you need to know what your client means when he talks about "SAP". Because as I said, "SAP" is a company, not a product. It's like asking "how do I connect with Microsoft?". If your client is a big company, you're most likely dealing with SAP ERP or CRM and you would need some RFC client library to connect to the system. There is a RFC client for PHP, but it is really old and probably won't work anymore: http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/. Another option would be web services, but you'd need your client to create them for you first.

Comment: my client told me to do yourself , so i will go for RFC as you told , and i must have ABAP development Skills to develop API for  communication

Comment: you don't need abap skills, but you're going to need help from your clients SAP support team identifying the function modules you need to call and the parameters you need to supply for those function modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105816/discussion-between-nexgen-technologies-llc-and-dirk-trilsbeek).

Answer (score 0):

I you're getting data from a (SAP) ECC HR system, ABAP (SAP ECC programming language) function module can be web-enabled by encapsulating them into a web-service. there is a 'simple' button for this. If you're not competent into the ABAP language, then just ask you're customer for the web service informations. This should be a black-box for you.

Comment: i understand but for what i ask to send me in information . means they will have provide me link for insertion